# Any difference between "Mueller matrix" and "Scattering matrix"?

Tags: terminology, scattering, s-matrix-theory

I find in some references 4x4 [Mueller matrix](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=mueller+matrix) and in other references 4x4 [Scattering matrix](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=scattering+matrix).

Are they different or identical?

If they are different, I would like to know the book or any research paper describing the relation between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among "these" $4\times 4$ matrices used for scattering, the Müller matrix and the scattering matrix are synonyma.  For example, this paper

> http://pre.aps.org/abstract/PRE/v58/i3/p3931_1

states that the $4\times 4$ scattering matrix is known as the Müller matrix.

The term "scattering matrix" is more general because it may be used for more general objects. For example, in particle physics, the $\infty\times\infty$ matrix encoding all possible transitions between the initial state of particles and the final state of particles is known as the S-matrix which may also be expanded as "the scattering matrix" (due to contributions of John Wheeler) although some fans of German science could argue that the name spread with Werner Heisenberg and his word "Streumatrix".

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Lubos Motl. Now I can assure that the definition of them.